# Custom Progress Dialog in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

How to create a Custom progress Dialoge in android with an image in it.
I am trying to create A base Progress dialog with an image rotating inside it.Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs library! It's really simple. You can create all kinds of **material dialogs** you want. There is also a usefull **documentation**!

[Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)
follow Google Material Design guidelines.

Install by

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0'
}
```

And implement by

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
.title(R.string.progress_dialog)
.content(R.string.please_wait)
.progress(true, 0)
.show();
```